# mac osx cant find cronjob which opens safari every few seconds

Tags: macos, safari, cron

I´ve installed a cronjob under mac osx which opens/curl an URL. Everything works fine but now I deleted all cronjobs by

```
crontab -r
```

and I deleted all lines in the crontab and

```
crontab -l
```

does not deliver any entry. The problem is that safari still opens every few seconds. Its also blocks my reboot command. I have to shut it down manually then I can restart my mac. When I get my login screen where I can click my User-Button the mac does a short "flash". So the screen gets white for one short moment. Looks like if you do an screenshot on an Iphone. Safari opens itself on startup (There is no entry in the startupitem list) to execute the Url. Somehow it feels as if there is a cronjob running in the backround but I cannot find it! Thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo crontab -l -u root` to see if it is in root's crontab.

Comment: Or `sudo grep curl /usr/lib/cron/tabs/*`

Comment: No that doesn´t work. There´s no file.

Comment: Try temporarily adding another cron job and see if that causes a crontab file to be created in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs` to be sure we are looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this script to see if you can spot the `curl` process being run, then you can find its Parent Process Id (PPID) in column 3, and then see the PID of the calling process. That will tell you how it is getting launched - or by whom, at least.

```
while :; do ps -aef | egrep "UID|curl" ; sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. I had a .plist in /Library/LaunchAgents calling my URL. I deleted it, remove from trash and restared computer. No it´s gone. Yes.